# Fill color of font to be different from background

Tags: android, fonts

I know how to use a font.ttf as a type face in my app. However when I use a font that has a bubbly look ( hallow areas) then the inside of the font takes the background color

For example, my background color is green and the font color is red then letter O is filled with green color. I would like it to be white? How can I achieve that. Do fonts support "fill color"?  Games like clash of clans and any other games have always fonts that have filled color different from background color ( unless an image is used instead of the text).

Any idea?

Comment: "Games like clash of clans and any other games have always fonts that have filled color different from background color ( unless an image is used instead of the text)" -- or they customized the font to have the fill they want. I am not aware of specifying an in-font fill color, though I can't rule out the possibility, at least at very low levels (e.g., `Canvas`, OpenGL).

Comment: Oh so you would think every letter is being drawn Seperatly using canvas, and not using a ttf file or call a method that fills  the font inside?

Comment: Personally, I'd customize the font. My point regarding `Canvas` is that you aren't going to find APIs for filling hollow areas of characters in higher-order stuff like `TextView`. I don't use `TextPaint` and stuff much, but if there's a hope for offering it in Java, it'd be at the `Canvas`/`TextPaint` layer.